# MySQL: Buffer pool instance lookup

Tags: mysql, performance, database-administration, database-tuning, mysqladministrator

In MySQL V5.5.38, I have two buffer pool instances and when warmup sql was executed, data from a particular table was split among the two instances (identified this using innodb_buffer_page table) . Now, when I execute a query with a non-indexed column in where clause, how does it decide which buffer pool instance to search ??

If the data we are looking for is not in the particular instance, 
 (1) does it load it to that instance or 
 (2) does it search the other instance before hitting the disk ?

Any information on this topic would be helpful.